# have i to lock mutex on queue front access

Tags: c++, multithreading, iterator, queue

i have a (**std::)queue** / **(std::)deque** which pushed by one thread and popped by an other. so i know i have to lock a mutex on push and pop functions because they are modifying the queue, but do i also have to lock a mutex if i access the front()?

the reason why i am asking is, i don't really know how the queue is organized internally. i've read something that it is allocation/deleting on time it is needed. so if i read the front while the other thread is pushing, **is it possible that the front is moved**?

and how about iterators? **do i also have to lock the mutex while an iterator is reading a value?**

i think it is always a good idea to lock the mutex while reading but i'm not sure if it is really needed to lock the whole queue.mutex on every iterator/front access. it may slow down the the whole programm if it locks everytime.

Comment: `std::queue` does not expose any iterators to its data, so you don't have to worry about the last point. Not sure about `std::queue/std::deque` though, I am not familiar with that data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) is just an adapter, which uses [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) or [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) internally.

You won't just lock the queue on reading, but wait on a condition variable and check if there's data available at all. If you have this setup

```
std::queue<int> q;
std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;
```

then you can wait for other threads providing data

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(m);
while(q.empty())
    cv.wait(guard);

int n = q.front();
q.pop();
```

which will be notified, when data becomes available

```
cv.notify_one();
```

for example.

Comment: so if i understand the std::libs properly, the (de)que(ue) is not moving the items like std::vector?

Comment: @pi88el `std::queue` is just using `std::deque`. And `std::deque` is a sequence container like `std::vector`. So, `std::deque` *might* move around or copy its elements, if needed.

Comment: @pi88el Even if `deque` wouldn't move its elements, you must use a lock, because `front()` + `pop()` is not atomic.

Comment: I concur if there are multiple readers. Since a queue is an adapter of an underlying container if the container chosen is a deque (the default) you *can* safely read and pop one end on a single thread while pushing data in the other simultaneously on another. However, as soon as you introduce an additional reader you *must* latch front-access as you have nicely demonstrated here. (and +1, I'd up-vote it again just for the nice sample of the mt-classes =)

Comment: @WhozCraig You can do so if there's just one reader *and* data is available. If the queue is empty, you must block somehow or do other work.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Agreed. The notification system not withstanding (which is an excellent side-sample of how to use a condition variable with a mutex for predicate monitoring, props for that), my comment was more for the iterator, reference, and pointer validity of deque content. Your example is spot-on.

Comment: @OlafDietsche, if you only insert/erase at the ends of a `std::deque` then it will **not** move elements around

Comment: @JonathanWakely I separated the variables from the lock. Hope, it's clearer now.